# Get number of hours between dates excluding weekends

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, recursive-query, mysql-8.0

I need to calculate the hours between two dates, one of them being NOW(), excluding weekends.
I have found a few solutions that use stored procedures or mysql functions, but i'm looking to do this within a single query.

I can get the general hour difference by using this:

`SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), created_at))`

But I need this to only return hours of weekdays, not weekends. So from Friday at 23:00 to Monday at 1:00 there should only be a 2 hour difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Mysql 8

Comment: This is quite hard.  This requires come calculation.  Databases are good for retrieving stuff, they are not good for performing calculations on stuff.  I would recommend that you stop looking to do this within a single query.  Even if someone provides a solution, it will be a monstrosity. You can do this a lot more elegantly in an actual programming language.

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: @akina I just updated. Version 8.

Comment: Generate weekend dates list within source dates range in CTE. Parse each period dividing it on separate days in another CTE. Join and remove weekdays. Group and calculate the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a programming language you'd write a loop and sum up the hours by iterating through the days. In SQL you can do the same with a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte (id, dt, minutes) as
(
  select
    id,
    date(created_at),
    case
      when dayofweek(created_at) in (1, 7) then 0
      else timestampdiff(minute, created_at, least(now(), date(created_at) + interval 1 day))
    end
  from mytable
  union all
  select
    id,
    dt + interval 1 day,
    case
      when dayofweek(dt + interval 1 day) in (1, 7) then 0
      else timestampdiff(minute, dt + interval 1 day, least(now(), dt + interval 2 day))
    end
  from cte
  where dt + interval 1 day <= curdate()
)
select id, round(sum(minutes) / 60, 1) as hours
from cte
group by id
order by id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a08f96bc29fb8a51302da10679496e22

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @thorstenkettner are you able to do a version of this also allowing for working hours eg 0900 to 1700? (please)

Comment: @Lyndon Penson: I suggest [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to get from a datetime to strings like '15:34' or '1534' which you can compare with your desired date range.